# when running spring Boot application getting required a bean of type that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MileageFeeController.class, args);    
  }
}
```

```java
@Controller
public class MileageFeeController { 
  @Autowired 
  MileageFeeCalculator calc;

  public float mileageFee( int miles) {
    System.out.println("Helloe");
    return calc.mileageCharge(miles);
  }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class MileageFeeCalculator {
  @Autowired
  private MileageRateService rateService; 

  public float mileageCharge(int miles) {
    return (miles * rateService.ratePerMile());
  }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class MileageRateService {
  public float ratePerMile() {
    return 0.565f;
  }
}
```

While executing above code getting below errors

```
com.demo.DemoApplication : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17 on N13115 with PID 9336 (D:\Spring Tool\SpringWorkSpace\Demo\target\classes started by jitendra2.k in D:\Spring Tool\SpringWorkSpace\Demo)
com.demo.DemoApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mileageFeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'calc'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.demo.MileageFeeCalculator' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2022-01-15 20:28:39.643 ERROR 9336 --- [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter: 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field calc in com.demo.MileageFeeController required a bean of type 'com.demo.MileageFeeCalculator' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.demo.MileageFeeCalculator' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with below change in DemoApplication class. Instead of passing MileageFeeController.class to SpringApplication.run, pass DemoApplication.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

As you mentioned you have to MileageFeeController.mileageFee method, you should run SpringBoot application as CommandLineRunner as below.

CommandLineRunner has a run method which you can use to trigger MileageFeeController.mileageFee method

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    MileageFeeController feeController;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println(feeController.mileageFee(5));
    }
}
```

Comment: if we make this it will execute only demoapplication class. how other class will execute.

Comment: Let me try to understand your requirement. You wanted to execute MileageFeeController.mileageFee method as part of spring boot application?

Comment: Yes MileageFeeController.mileageFee method i want to execute

Comment: You should implement CommandLineRunner, which has a run method that can be used to execute your MileageFeeController.mileageFee  method. Updated answer.

Comment: I done changes like above mentioned after execute getting below errors org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demoApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'feeController'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mileageFeeController